# How do I resolve eslint import/no-named-as-default

Tags: javascript, eslint, es6-modules

After looking at the documentation for the import/no-named-as-default eslint rule, I'm still confused about what exactly I'm doing wrong.

I have the following file structure

```
.
├── ButtonBack.css
├── ButtonBack.jsx
├── __tests__
│   └── ButtonBack.test.jsx
└── index.js
```

The ButtonBack.jsx contains the following code

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class ButtonBack extends React.Component {
  ... code removed to keep example short ...
}
```

__tests__/ButtonBack.test.jsx contains the following code

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ButtonBack from '../ButtonBack'; // <== this line has an eslint warning

... code removed to keep example short ...
```

The problem is, my linter says that `import ButtonBack from '../ButtonBack` violates the following lint rules:

- [import/no-named-as-default](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-named-as-default.md)
- [import/no-named-as-default-member](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-named-as-default-member.md)

I can't figure out why my import statement violates the lint rule.  Removing the name of the class in ButtonBack.jsx (`export default class extends React.Component`) does not solve the issue either.

Comment: Are there any other `export`s in `ButtonBack.jsx`, or just the `export default class ButtonBack`?

Comment: Just the one export.

Comment: did you get to a solution on this or did you just disable the rule?

Comment: I just disabled the rule. 

Comment: This ESLint rule is lame

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Ran into this same issue and from what I'm seeing you're going to just have to disable that rule (that's what I did at least)

"Unfortunately, React + Redux is the most common scenario. However, there are lots of other cases where HOCs will force developers to shut down this rule."

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/544

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/119

https://github.com/18F/calc/pull/1235

.eslintrc

```
"rules": {
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0
}
```

Answer (score 38):

Ran into this issue because I am using `React` + `Redux`:

```
export class ButtonBack extends React.Component {
  // code removed
}
export default connect(null, null)(ButtonBack);
```

So with the code above this import will give me a warning:

```
import ButtonBack from ./ButtonBack;
```

changing to the following fixes the problem:

```
import ConnectedButtonBack from ./ButtonBack;
```

Not exporting `class ButtonBack` would also fix the problem, but I like to export it to [help with testing](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components).

---

#### UPDATE 2019

My preferred solution for this issue is to **have separate files for components and container**. I think this keeps files smaller and easier to understand.
In this case I would have two files:

```
components/ButtonBack.js
containers/ButtonBackContainer.js
```

---

#### UPDATE 2020

The [no-named-as-default](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-named-as-default.md#importno-named-as-default) eslint rule is meant to help you in case you mistakenly import a `default export` when you meant to import a `named export`.

I haven't ran into this issue for a while now because:

- I [avoid default exports](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2019/01/stop-using-default-exports-javascript-module/) when I can, as I think they can lead to mild confusion.
- I don't use the `connect` function anymore, I use the [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples) hook instead.
- I usually test the component together with the `redux store`. [Here](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux) is an example on how to do that using **React Testing Library**.

Comment: another solution would be "  import { ButtonBack } from ./ButtonBack;  "   I prefer this solution if I want to keep the same component name in the import also.

Comment: @arun8 if you are using redux, thats not a solution. `import { ButtonBack } from ./ButtonBack;` and `import ConnectedButtonBack from ./ButtonBack;` are two different things. One is the plain component and the other is the connected component.

Comment: Personally I feel that the calling something "ConnectedButtonBack" is very clunky. Additionally I think having two files that don't serve a hugely different purpose and are directly linked is also clunky. I personally call my pure function _ButtonBack, then export the connected component. That way I can do `import { _ButtonBack }` if I need the pure version (usually just for tests) and `import ButtonBack` if I need the connected version. It's less noise than adding the words "Pure" or "Connected" or similar all over the place. Just my opinion!

Comment: @MattFletcher Naming it `_ButtonBack` gives the impression it is private and should not be touched. Don't you think that goes against React's design--where we want to have reusable components?

Comment: @doug They're reusable components still- it's only that the naming convention is annoying because it's often used elsewhere to suggest privacy when really nothing in JS is private.

Comment: I'm relatively new to React and TS so I'm still bumping into things that might be more obvious to more experienced React/TS developers. The update you made for 2020 ended up being the issue I was running into.

Answer (score 25):

Original problem line :

```
import ButtonBack from '../ButtonBack';
```

Fixed Line:

```
import { ButtonBack } from '../ButtonBack';
```

Comment: Whilst this may work in the general case, you need to be careful if you are using react/redux, and therefore wrapping your react component in the `connect()(yourCompnent)` method from redux. If you wrap the export in curly braces, you will not export the connected component.

Comment: easy answer, but I don't know what it fixes, since my export was default

Comment: Nice and Precise Answer...Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when I imported class components and it was such a simple solution in the end.

## Solution

Just add

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

to your eslintrc config file after you installed this package with

```
npm install babel-eslint --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add babel-eslint --dev
```

## Explanation

**babel-eslint** tells eslint to use the configuration specified in my Babel configuration file. There I have specified that I use React and that's why eslint will not complain anymore. This is how my Babel configuration file looks like:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is rather silly for esLint but what I did to resolve it was to check file that is exporting, I accidentally had export class then export default connect. Still had lint error, re wrote import line in parent and eslint cleared warning.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an exception in .eslintrc

```
"rules": {
  "import/prefer-default-export": "off"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use an alias at export and the opposite alias on import

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem while importing faker js
I am importing like this:

```
import faker from '@faker-js/faker'
```

and getting eslint error:

> warning  Using exported name 'faker' as an
> identifier for default export  import/no-named-as-default

The solution which worked for me is :

```
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker'
```

So, in your case, you just need to change your importing to this

```
import {ButtonBack} from '../ButtonBack';
```