# Get past import/no-named-as-default lint error without config changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting no-named-as-default eslint error.

Having issues where I need Redux functionality and I can't just go for named imports.

Seen similar queries here but they all involve config changes like amending the eslint file

or things to do with Babel configs.

Example: [How do I resolve eslint import/no-named-as-default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437203/how-do-i-resolve-eslint-import-no-named-as-default)

Is there a way to achieve it in code itself?

Cos I can't change any of the configs. I am ok to forgo default import all together and use 
2x named imports (maybe 1 with an alias?).

But I can't seem to do away with default. The bottom export complains when I remove it.

Also unsure if eslint will start complaining if there is no default imports on a Component.

This is the component which the eslint complains about if I import this as default.

```
export const IndicatorPage = ({setData}) => {
    // logic
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setData: setIndicatorData
}

// ide complains if I remove this default. Plus even if I could drop default, 
// wondering if that would be another lint error for not having defaults 
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(IndicatorPage);
```

Example when I import this in another Component.

This makes eslint happy but it breaks my redux functionality.

```
import { IndicatorPage } from './IndicatorPage';
```

This makes Redux work properly but now eslint complains...

```
import IndicatorPage from './IndicatorPage';
```

Comment: is `eslint-disable-next-line` an option?

Comment: @lastr2d2 No its not an option..

Comment: I don't think default import has to do anything on redux. Can you please let us know, what error are you getting on the Redux side?

Comment: @Sam The setData prop comes up as undefined if I use named import.

Comment: Can you please add your setIndicatorData function and from where it is referenced?